# One word to describe = 'era inappropriate'

Tags: single-word-requests

One word to describe a 'tangible thing' (like tool, technology, architecture), 'concept or ideology', etc. that does not belong to a period. Like: envisioning crusaders riding into battle wearing a Timex watch - or - trying to enforce religious, social order/doctrine/clothing that is/are just impractical for the current age/era. Something to convey = 'era inappropriate'.... in the sense that it either did not exist or is impractical.

Answer (score 3):

*[anachronic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/anachronic)* also *anachronistic*:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Relating to or involving *[anachronism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/anachronism)*:
>
> NOUN
>
> 1 A thing belonging or appropriate to a period other than that in
>   which it exists, especially a thing that is conspicuously
>   old-fashioned:
>
> Origin
>
> mid 17th century: from Greek anakhronismos, from ana- 'backward' +
>   khronos 'time'.

Answer (score 2):

anachronistic is the more common variant of the term.